# Strange Iframe Scaling on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having some problems with an iframe. I'm embeding this website using an iframe and on desktop it looks right, even if I play around with the windows size it's responsive, but when I try to see the iframe from a mobile device, it shows the contents zoomed out. (The iframe takes 100% of the browser screen size)

This is how the iframe shows the website: [image]

And this is how it should look like:

[image]

```html
<style type="text/css">
body {
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.container{
    width:50%;
}
#iframe1 {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" frameborder="0"  
     src="https://just4metin.ro/"></iframe>
     </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: did you try opening the website itself via the same mobile you used? what do you get there?

Comment: If I open the website itself on the mobile device, it shows scaled correctly as in the second picture

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_iframes.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .responsive-iframe {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <iframe id="iframe1" class="responsive-iframe" src="https://just4metin.ro/"></iframe>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, @MrJami helped me out with that link.

The problem was that I didn't include this meta:

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```